# AngularJs: doubts implementing controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller

I'm implementing my first AngularJS controller in a test application and I'm having some difficulties.

I have a list of items that I'm getting from a RESTful web service and I'm trying to implement a basic CRUD logic for this items.

The list is shown in `itemsList.htm` page and **routing config** is:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/items',
            {
                controller: 'ItemsController',
                templateUrl: 'app/Partials/itemsList.htm'
            })
        .when('/items/:itemID',
            {
                controller: 'ItemsController',
                templateUrl: 'app/Partials/editItem.htm'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/items' });
});
```

Then I have my `ItemsController`:

```
app.controller('ItemsController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, itemsService) {
    $scope.status;
    $scope.items;

    getItems();

    function getItems() {
        itemsService.getItems()
            .success(function (items) {
                $scope.items = items;   
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load items: ' + error.message;
            });
    }

    function getItem(ID) {
        // ...  
    }
}
```

Now I want to add to the same controller a function that returns a certain item passing its ID and populate `editItem.htm` page, but I don't know I to access this functon...

I mean: how can I map the path `/items/:itemID` to this function?
Should I implement it in a different controller and change the route config?

**NOTE** I usually implement my web apps using Java and Spring MVC and I usually implement a single controller for each entity in my application (for example: ItemsController, CustomersController, etc.). Is it correct to follow this rule also with AngularJs or there is some other best-practice?

Comment: sort of $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (scope, next, current) {
    var path = $location.path();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go about it would be to implement a `ItemController` that handles only one item at a time. Again it depends upon how the html is structured.

In any case you need to retrieve the selected item id using the $routeParams collection.

In the controller you can do

```
if($routeParams.itemID) {
   //you got the id. call the getItem
   getItem(itemID).success(function(item) {
       $scope.item=data;
   });
}
```

This piece has to be added in either ItemsController if you use the same controller, or in case you create a new controller still same check would be required.

If you are using existing ItemsController the implementation should be like

```
 if($routeParams.itemID) {
       //same as above code
 }
 else {
     getItems();
 }
```

which means you dont want to load list in the scope for single item view.

Comment: What do you mean with: _"to implement a ItemController that handles only one item at a time"_? So what should be the right way to implement my controller? Sorry but I'm completely new to AngularJS...

Comment: ItemsController can be used for listing of items, sorting, filtering etc. For action on a single item there can be a ItemController, which can support single item actions such as create, edit, delete, update etc. You are currently using the same controller for both the scenarios\views.

Comment: uh, ok... I didn't noticed the Items/Item difference... :)
It's a bit strange for me, in Spring MVC I usually implement a controller for each entity (i.e. ItemsController, CustomersController, etc.). But, ok... I'll follow your suggestion. Thank you.